# Regex for all chars and new lines except symbols

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

My task is to write a parser in C# that will convert string to html code. Now, I am parsing string using regex, so, my code looks like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\n?\[s=(.*)?\](?:\n?(.*)?\n?)?\[\/s\]\n?");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(CurrentPage.FAQ);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="n">@match.Groups[1].Value</div>
        <div class="tt">@Html.Raw(match.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\r", "<br />").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"))</div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that regex expression `\n?\[s=(.*)?\](?:\n?(.*)?\n?)?\[\/s\]\n?` is valid only if strings looks like.

```
[s=hello]This is demo text![/s]
```

If there apears to be a new line in text, its not validating. For example

```
[s=hello]
     This is demo list
          1. Hello world!
          2. List item
[/s]
```

I tried to modify my expression to `\n?\[s=(.*)?\](?:\n?((.|\n)*)?\n?)?\[\/s\]\n?` but the string can contain one or more [s] items, so it validates it as one

```
[s=hello](BEGINING TO VALIDATE FROM HERE)This is demo text![/s]
[s=hello]
     This is demo list
          1. Hello world!
          2. List item
(TO HERE)[/s]
```

Thats why it validate it as a item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead like below and don't forget to enable DOTALL `(?s)` modifier to make dot in your regex to match even line breaks also.

```
@"(?s)\[s=([^\[\]]*)\]((?:(?!\[\/s]).)*)\[\/s]"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA4lM0/1)